# Get previously visited page ID

Tags: id, previous

I would like to get the ID (or permalink) of the page the visitor visited just before visiting the current page - in other words the ID of the last page in the browser history.

Can this be done? Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Search inside the `print_r( $GLOBALS );` array. Not sure right now, but it maybe inside `$_GET/_REQUEST/_SESSION/_SERVER;`...

Comment: @kaiser cheers, there is indeed a HTTP_REFERER in _SERVER - giving me the URL of the previous page. Perfect!

Comment: This might be useful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Break this down into two parts:

First, we create a variable that stores that last-visited page URL, like this:

```
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

Then, you could either use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to trim down everything between *?=* and the */* after the ID number. like this:

```
$prev_url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/?p=123';
$id_block = substr($prev_url, strpos($prev_url, "?p=")+1);
$id = substr($id_block, 0, strpos($id_block, "/"));
```

.. Or, you could use [jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722360/jquery-get-part-of-string) to achieve the same.

I haven't tested this but it should work - let me know how it does!
Good luck ;)

Comment: thanks - i was already thinking in this direction, but php manual sais about this: "The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**" So I'm a bit in doubt whether it's the best way to go...

Comment: True - the HTTP_REFERER depends on the server alone. To be honest, I am unaware of any other solutions for this. If this is not a crucial function, I would go ahead and use HTTP_REFERER as it is pretty stable from agent to agent.

Comment: It's not a crucial function, so I'll just go with this & provide a fallback scenario.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this trick like this to allow me to also check if it is one of my pages :

//Get the last page link from history

```
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
```

//Check if not null and if it contains my blog url

```
if( !empty( $prev_url ) || strpos( $prev_url, (string)get_blog_details()->domain ) !== false ) :
    //Then display it only if it's one of my blog page ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $prev_url; ?>" class="previous-history-link">The last page from history</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just a sidenote here, `HTTP_REFERER` is unreliable as this can be turned of by the end user, so never rely on that