# Help getting previously visited pages ID

Tags: php, id

I'm using ACF plugin and I want to pull a custom field from the previous page.

I have a WP site that has a homepage and then 20 sub pages. Each sub page is for a specific city and each city has its own contact phone number. Then interested viewers will go to an apply page.

So the flow will hopefully be HOME » Your city page » Apply page. Rather than make an Apply page for every city, I want to pull the custom field from the city page the viewer visited before arriving at the apply page.

I found this info: [Get previously visited page ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35775/get-previously-visited-page-id)

But it's a bit advanced for me. Anyone willing to dumb it down and show me what this might look like in practice?

The ACF plugin has the ability to pull a custom field from another page using IDs:

```
<p><?php the_field('city_phone', 123); ?></p>
```

That would return the custom field city_phone from post 123. How would I get the previous pages ID into 123?

Answer (score 2):

[`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) should help you here. Something like this

```
<php
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
if ( $prev_url ) {
    $prev_path = str_replace( home_url(), '', $prev_url );
    $page = get_page_by_path( $prev_path );
}
```

That should give you the page object, where you can access it's ID like so - `$page->ID`.